# table in td tag, i want table to start from the top how do i make it possible?

Tags: html, css

```css
.td_1 {
     width:30%;
      border: 1px solid #ff7171;/*red*/
      padding-right: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      position: static;
    }

    .td_1_table {
     margin: 0px;
     
     float: right; 
     }
```

```html
<table>
    
    <td class="td_1">
    
    This is test
    <table class="td_1_table" border="1" width="200" height="300" cellspacing="0"></table>
    
    </td>
    (...)
    <table>
```

[image]

my table start from middle! which i want to prevent..
how do i put it top?

Comment: I just put your code in https://jsfiddle.net/zkb7sg9L/. there is no problem, is there?

Comment: use top:0; in your css

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a vertical-align: top; on the .td_1 class, that should do the trick. Also make sure to close the table tag at the end

Comment: No worries,  if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.td_1 {
        width:30%;
         border: 1px solid #ff7171;
         padding-right: 10px;
         margin-right: 10px;
         position: static;
         vertical-align: top; 
    }